# Wildcard while comparing strings on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, compare, wildcard

I need to compare 2 Strings, is there any wildcard character?

In case that there is none wildcard, how can i do this? The strings to compare are concatenations of substrings like this HHH-H-HHH separated by ','.

Example:

```
var str1 = "HHH-H-HHH,OOO-O-OOO"

var str2 = "HHH-$-HHH,OOO-O-OOO"

var str3 = "HHH-H-HHH,OOO-$-OOO"

var str4 = "HHH-H-HHH,OOO-U-OOO"

str1.equals(str2) // SHOULD BE TRUE

str1.equals(str3) // SHOULD BE TRUE

str1.equals(str4) // SHOULD BE FALSE
```

Comment: See https://regexone.com/lesson/wildcards_dot and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match Also, the code you have written is Java: JavaScript has no native `String.prorotype.equals()` method.

Comment: @msanford https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

Answer (score 3):

Use regex:

```js
var str1 = "HHH-H-HHH,OOO-O-OOO"
var str2 = "HHH-H-HHH,OOO-U-OOO"

var rgx1 = /HHH-.*-HHH,OOO-O-OOO/
var rgx2 = /HHH-H-HHH,OOO-.*-OOO/

console.log(rgx1.test(str1)) // SHOULD BE TRUE
console.log(rgx2.test(str1)) // SHOULD BE TRUE
console.log(str1 === str2) // SHOULD BE FALSE
```

The `.*` operator in regex matches anything, so that's your wildcard. Note that this way you have to make a distinction between values and patterns. That is, there are the strings you want to check, and the patterns you want to check them against (represented here by the regexes).

If you're comparing against a pattern, use a regex (first two examples). If you're comparing two values, just do it directly with the `===` operator (last example).

Comment: As Bergi correctly pointed out, `.test()` is better since it returns a boolean (so no need to `!!`).

Comment: Yeah if you see my original comment I got on the `match()` train too quickly, too. :)